# Understanding React Joins for my Cruise Ship Website

Tags: reactjs, join, knex.js

I am trying to get an understanding on how I can use knex joins for my React cruise ship website.

It is meant to work like this :

On Cruise Lines Page it has buttons for the Cruise Lines and when you click on a Cruise Line, a list of ships appears. When you click on a ship from the list it takes you to that ship on a Review Page for the Cruise Line.

The ship is taken from a ships.js seeds file and there is a reviews.js seeds file as well https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/tree/robs-shipslist-under-cruiselines/seeds.

I have changed to using review_id in ships.js to connect to reviews.js, is this how you make the initial connection ?

If it exists one initial review can be displayed for a ship on the review page.

There is also a Make a Review button for a user who wants to add a review for a ship and this goes through a form process and gets added for a ship.

What I am wanting to understand is how I can use joins to connect a ship with a review ?

I have not got a complete understanding on how the backend connects with the frontend for joins and if there is code needed in the api ?

So far I have my code for the joins in a database like this :

```
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
const config = require('../../knexfile')[environment]
const db = require('knex')(config)


function getReviews()   {
    const db = testConn || db
    console.log('server/db/dbreviews.js getReviews called!')

return db('ships')
    .join('reviews','ships.id', '=', 'reviews.ship_id')
    .where('ship_id', '=', id)
    .select("*", "ships.id AS sid", "reviews.id AS rid")
    .first()
    .then(record => {
        console.log(record)
        console.log('Ship' + record.Review_User_Name + 'has a' + record.Review + ' ' + record.StarRating + '' + record.Cruise_Name 
        + '' + record.Sail_Date + '' + record.Leaving_Port + '' + record.Destination + '' + record.Travel_Name + ''
        + record.Review_Title + '' + record.Number_of_Cruises + '' + record.Travel_Party)
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('dbreviews.js - GOT Reviews')
            return dbrecord
})
}

module.exports = {
    getReviews
}
```

Comment: I have been stuck on this for a while and going forward I just need to get an understanding on how these joins work.

If anyone has a good understanding on how this is meant to work for a situation like mine, may you please share your ideas that may help.

Comment: should every ship have multiple reviews ?

Comment: @AbedMurrar 
Initially a ship can have one initial review from the reviews table, but only if it exists. 
When the user wants to make a review that is when multiple reviews get added for a ship. 
There is a Make a Review button for the user to click and it goes through a from process for adding a review for a ship. 

Would I have joins for both of these situations or could the initial review be controlled by the join and the added review controlled through the form process ?

I am trying to work out how joins work in a situation like this.

Comment: You should look at the bigger picture here, the `Ship` is an isolated entity, but the `Review` is a weak entity, meaning that there would be no review if there was no ship. so in that case, in order to make a `Review` a weak entity, the foreign key should be placed in the reviews table, and not in the ship table, because the review depends on the existence of the ship, but the ship does not depend on the existence of a review.

Comment: @AbedMurrar
I see what you mean by the review depends on existence of the ship, but ship does not depend on existence of a review. 
Also for my situation the ship always exists, but the review does not , so going by what you have told me, I would think that the foreign key should be ship_id in reviews table and not review_id in ships table, is this how it is meant to work ?  

Once I have the foreign key worked out, how does the joins work with the front-end and back end ?

I am trying to get an overall understanding on these joins.

Comment: @AbedMurrar
Hi Abed just wondering if you had the chance to look at my reply ?
It is most important that I get an understanding on how joins work with the front end and back end for a situation like mine, so that I can finish my cruise ship website.
Also confirming that I should be having ship_id in reviews table for the join to work with ships table?

Hopefully this is not the point where I never here back from you again, as this can sometimes happen on these forum channels.